# Error: QueryFrame not a member of cv

Tags: c++, opencv

When I run my `opencv` code on raspbian i get the following error:

```
error: "CaptureFromCAM" is not a member of cv
error: "SetCaptureProperty" is not a member of cv
error: "QueryFrame" is not a member of cv
```

Can anyone help with the correct notations as I am using `opencv` 3.0. The code runs without errors on a lower version.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: code is quit lengthy so i cant post it here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on berak's answer:

The OpenCV C-API is a relic that should not be used unless you really have to. This has been the case for a long, long time.
There are apparently still ways to access the old C API if you still need to. See the comment by berak on this post.

To capture video you should be using the [`cv::VideoCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) class in the C++ API. The link shows usage examples as well as the class reference.

If you have old code which uses the old C-API, your only options are to either remain on OpenCV 2.x, or rewrite to the C++ API.

Comment: I do not agree that one should ever stay with the old C-API. It should be long dead by now ;)

Comment: In theory, yes. There might be some very specific reasons why you might not be able to upgrade though. You might have a really old application that you need to interface with, for example. Or just a policy decision to use the C API (for whatever reason). If you don't have any such reasons, then yes, one should stay away from the old interface. Personally I tend to use the Python bindings.

Comment: I 100% agree with you on that, thats why I added the ";)". The thing is just that 90% of people who ask about the old api use it because of some tutorial from ancient times and don´t know what they are doing. Burrying the old C-Api as deep as possible could fix that hopefully.

Comment: let me clarify, they removed the **python** (c-based) cv api entirely with opencv3.0. also the c-headers are no more automatically included from the c++ ones, you need `opencv/core_c.h` etc. so, while it's still possible to keep the arcane c code until the sun melts, anyone should be highly encouraged to make an end to this montrosity.

Comment: @berak, Ok, I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

the deprecated cv python api was removed from opencv3.0, CaptureFromCAM, etc are no more available.

please use opencv's cv2 api in python:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("win")

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while camera.isOpened():
    ok, image=camera.read()
    if not ok:
        print 'no image read'
        break
    cv2.imshow("win", image)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == 27 : break # esc pressed
```

Comment: Thanks berak but im not using python so can you please suggest the replacement for c++.

Comment: again, do not use any of those deprecated c-functions, but stick to opencv's c++ api. cv::VideoCapture, cv::Mat, etc.